# Parsing npm command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have got a script which replaces data in the database and I want to run this script with `npm command`

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "database": "node devData/database.js --delete & node devData/database.js --import"
  },
```

**database.js**

```
if (process.argv[2] === '--import') {
    importData();
} else if (process.env[2] === '--delete') {
    deleteData();
}
```

The key here is the `&` I guess. With this solution only the first part of `npm command` is recognized which is `--delete`.

I changed npm command in `package.json` to `"node devData/database.js --delete ; node devData/database.js --import"` and then inside `database.js` I'm running `forEach` to check whether I've got `--import` or `--delete`

```
process.argv.forEach(part => {
    part === '--delete' ? deleteData() : part === '--import' ? importData() : '';
})
```

Solution works but I have to run it sometimes twice due to uploading same content to `db` which gives me duplicate error.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your first code in database.js checks argv for one and process.env for other - shouldn’t both checks be argv?

Comment: I didn't see that one coming, you're right, that was a typo, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run one command and then, after it succeeds, run the second command, right? For that, use `&&` which is the shell "and" operator. (Using a single `&` instructs the shell to put the first command in the background.)

```
"scripts": {
    "database": "node devData/database.js --delete && node devData/database.js --import"
  },
```

With the `&&` operator, the second command runs unless the first command exits with an error code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for advice but unfortunately it does not solve the problem. Only first part of the command works but --import is not triggered and is not visible when I console.log(process.argv[2]). If I switch the order I can import data

Comment: If import is not run in this case, it's because the delete command exited with an error code. That's what the `&&` is all about.

Comment: Okey I solved the problem, your comment gave me a hint. I was missing process.exit() inside importData and deleteData functions in try catch block. After adding it, it works as expected. I checked & and && solution works no matter the & in this case. Thanks!